Countdown indicator on bountied questions
I don't know if this has been discussed before, I didn't find anything in the search engine.
I usually check the bountied in the stacks I participate in, often to check the pending time. I don't know if in the general case, but in my particular case a countdown indicator would be useful, this would save me from having to open the same question several times. I also don't know how it would work on more complicated pages like Stackoverflow where I got the example screenshot:


Yeah this was already asked for before, this is the search I've used to find it.

After reading the question and all the comments, I did not find any answer, solution, suggestion or inconvenience. It would be great to have some positive or negative option regarding the feasibility or impossibility of execution, especially from users more experienced than me in using the site.

Duplicates on Meta work differently. It’s not “this should resolve your problem” so much as “this has been asked for before.”

This is technically possible, like most requests, and looks like it should not be very complex to do. However, with hundreds of bugs and requests, SE has to prioritize them, and naturally some will get less love. Nothing we can do, and for things like this, many people write and use userscripts, you can find most here. Looks like there isn't one that do what you ask here, but it shouldn't be too hard to write, you can ask in chat and someone might actually do it one day, before SE.
